# Compare two version of gradle dependencies org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix 2.2.2.RELEASE vs 2.2.10.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

There's been recently a vulnerability CVE-2021-22044 in org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:2.2.2.RELEASE and Jenskins strongly recommended to upgrade it to 2.2.10.RELEASE

Having done that, I have troubles passing through Test stage during the build prossess as tests fail at **statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())**

```
    val returnAlarms = getAuthentication()
            .`when`()
            .param("page", page)
            .param("size", size)
            .param("sort", "statusCode,date")
            .param("priority", "CRITICAL")
            .get("$baseUrl/alarms")
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
            .and()
            .extract()
            .`as`<PagedResult<AlarmOverviewDto>>(type, jackson2Mapper)
```

Is there a way to see the difference between the versions 2.2.2.RELEASE and 2.2.10.RELEASE to find out what exactly causes the tests to fail and have it fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried to compare the versions in git already ?

Comment: @Marged No, it never occured to me to do it over git . Thanks for the advice!